# How to keep HTML/CSS element fixed and not jutter/adjust everytime the above element animation is triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

It's a nitpicky design thing but I basically have this element above my contact button below that makes makes list elements pop a little (using transforms and other rudimentary CSS animations knowledge that I pieced together), but now the button below stutters/jumps every time the above animation is triggered.

I am using zero JavaScript for this particular exercise (Just HTML/CSS) and I'd like to keep it that way but if it's a quick & small fix using JavaScript - then sure why not.

The HTML Sections in Question:

```
<div>
    <ul class="projectlist">
        <li class="slidein">&#127918 The Game</li>
        <li class="slidein">&#128296 The Toolbox</li>
        <li class="slidein">&#128218 The Resource</li>
        <li class="slidein">More projects...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="divbutton">
    <h2><a href="default.asp" target="_blank">Contact</a></h2>
</div>
```

The CSS related to the transforms for SlideIn:

```
.slidein:hover {
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    font-size: 19px;
    translate(0,0);
  }

  to {
    font-size:20px;
    translate(10,0);
  }
}
```

CSS related to the contact button for additional info if you need it:

```
.divbutton {
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
}

a {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 35px;
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: -20px;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: #59b515;
  color: white;
}


.projectlist {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'NowRegular';
    font-size: 19px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Here is also a video of the problem if you need it: [Youtube](https://youtu.be/eKECqqtcJoI)

Just the way the contact button skips there at the bottom.

I've already tried simple simple stuff like position fixed, absolute and all those and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens, because the animation changes the line-height of the links.

This should fix it:

```
.slidein {
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

Edit:
The animation should be configured on the class, without ":hover", otherwise the animation will only trigger if the mouse is on the element. when the mouse leves the element, the animation just does not end and it jumps to the default state.
A keyframe animation is not needet. you can just define the bigger font on the ":hover" selctor.

take a look here: https://codepen.io/unnamed-5-8-13/pen/mdmeMWq

Comment: You're a genius, thank you! (And yes it worked)

Comment: you're welcome :) I added a codepen with the added tips for a smoother animation.

Comment: You're too kind- I will definitely check it out , have a good day man